# Did any Gethenian ever have sex with a human?

Tags: sexuality, ursula-k-le-guin

Starting from "The Left hand of darkness", Usula Le Guin often returned to the people from [Gethen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gethen) (aka "Winter") and their peculiar biology: adults are, for the most of the month, totally androgynous without any sex drive or distinguishable gender. But during the few days of a month (called "Somer"), they develop gender and crave intimacy and sexual contacts.

In the "Left hand", a human - Genly Ai -  and Gethenian named Estraven spend a long time together far away from any population and, at least once, Estraven goes through Somer. Genly notices, that while he is slightly bigger than average "male" Gethenian, he still technically could have sex with Estraven, but he decides not to.

Has Le Guin even confirmed that at any stage there was a sexual relationship (of any sort) between a human and Gethenian?

Comment: Sure Gethenians are unusual, but they're still human, being descendant of the [Hainish](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hainish_Cycle).